# does downloading datasets on google colaboratory use my internet data?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory

when i use datasets from sklearn does colaboraory uses my internet data to download files? like:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing
```

or

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
```

[MNIST Dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

if it does is there a way to change it so google servers download it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't use your internet to download.

It downloads directly from Google's server. That's why it's very fast.